# Adding icons to wordpress navigation menu

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I want to add an icon after <a> which is in <li>.

I modified the file `class-walker-nav-menu.php`, added something like this, but the `if` condition doesn't work, without it, icons are added but to each element, and I want them to be added only to <li> that have children.

```
$item_output = $args->before;
$item_output .= $menu_item->has_children ? '<i class="icon1"></i>' : '';
$item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
$item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
$item_output .= '</a>';
$item_output .= $menu_item->has_children ? '<i class="icon2"></i>' : '';
$item_output .= $args->after;
```

And here is all code /

Thank you for your help!

```
<?php
/**
 * Nav Menu API: Walker_Nav_Menu class
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Nav_Menus
 * @since 4.6.0
 */

/**
 * Core class used to implement an HTML list of nav menu items.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @see Walker
 */

class Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker {
    /**
     * What the class handles.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @var string
     *
     * @see Walker::$tree_type
     */
    public $tree_type = array( 'post_type', 'taxonomy', 'custom' );

    /**
     * Database fields to use.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @todo Decouple this.
     * @var string[]
     *
     * @see Walker::$db_fields
     */
    public $db_fields = array(
        'parent' => 'menu_item_parent',
        'id'     => 'db_id',
    );

    /**
     * Starts the list before the elements are added.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker::start_lvl()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );

        // Default class.
        $classes = array( 'sub-menu' );
        // Add custom class to sub-menu.
        $classes[] = 'my-custom-class';

        /**
         * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu list element.
         *
         * @since 4.8.0
         *
         * @param string[] $classes Array of the CSS classes that are applied to the menu `<ul>` element.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of `wp_nav_menu()` arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $class_names = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', $classes, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= "{$n}{$indent}<ul$class_names>{$n}";


    }

    /**
     * Ends the list of after the elements are added.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker::end_lvl()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent  = str_repeat( $t, $depth );
        $output .= "$indent</ul>{$n}";
    }

    /**
     * Starts the element output.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @since 4.4.0 The {@see 'nav_menu_item_args'} filter was added.
     * @since 5.9.0 Renamed `$item` to `$data_object` and `$id` to `$current_object_id`
     *              to match parent class for PHP 8 named parameter support.
     *
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     *
     * @param string   $output            Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param WP_Post  $data_object       Menu item data object.
     * @param int      $depth             Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args              An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     * @param int      $current_object_id Optional. ID of the current menu item. Default 0.
     */
    public function start_el( &$output, $data_object, $depth = 0, $args = null, $current_object_id = 0 ) {
        // Restores the more descriptive, specific name for use within this method.
        $menu_item = $data_object;

        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( $t, $depth ) : '';

        $classes   = empty( $menu_item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $menu_item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $menu_item->ID;

        /**
         * Filters the arguments for a single nav menu item.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         *
         * @param stdClass $args      An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param WP_Post  $menu_item Menu item data object.
         * @param int      $depth     Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $menu_item, $depth );

        /**
         * Filters the CSS classes applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param string[] $classes   Array of the CSS classes that are applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param WP_Post  $menu_item The current menu item object.
         * @param stdClass $args      An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth     Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $class_names = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $menu_item, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        /**
         * Filters the ID attribute applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.1
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param string   $menu_item_id The ID attribute applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param WP_Post  $menu_item    The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args         An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth        Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $menu_item->ID, $menu_item, $args, $depth );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names . '>';

        $atts           = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $menu_item->attr_title ) ? $menu_item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $menu_item->target ) ? $menu_item->target : '';
        if ( '_blank' === $menu_item->target && empty( $menu_item->xfn ) ) {
            $atts['rel'] = 'noopener';
        } else {
            $atts['rel'] = $menu_item->xfn;
        }
        $atts['href']         = ! empty( $menu_item->url ) ? $menu_item->url : '';
        $atts['aria-current'] = $menu_item->current ? 'page' : '';

        /**
         * Filters the HTML attributes applied to a menu item's anchor element.
         *
         * @since 3.6.0
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param array $atts {
         *     The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's `<a>` element, empty strings are ignored.
         *
         *     @type string $title        Title attribute.
         *     @type string $target       Target attribute.
         *     @type string $rel          The rel attribute.
         *     @type string $href         The href attribute.
         *     @type string $aria-current The aria-current attribute.
         * }
         * @param WP_Post  $menu_item The current menu item object.
         * @param stdClass $args      An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth     Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $menu_item, $args, $depth );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( is_scalar( $value ) && '' !== $value && false !== $value ) {
                $value       = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $menu_item->title, $menu_item->ID );

        /**
         * Filters a menu item's title.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         *
         * @param string   $title     The menu item's title.
         * @param WP_Post  $menu_item The current menu item object.
         * @param stdClass $args      An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth     Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $menu_item, $args, $depth );

            $item_output = $args->before;
            $item_output .= $menu_item->has_children ? '<i class="icon1"></i>' : '';
            $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
            $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
            $item_output .= '</a>';
            $item_output .= $menu_item->has_children ? '<i class="icon2"></i>' : '';
            $item_output .= $args->after;


        /**
         * Filters a menu item's starting output.
         *
         * The menu item's starting output only includes `$args->before`, the opening `<a>`,
         * the menu item's title, the closing `</a>`, and `$args->after`. Currently, there is
         * no filter for modifying the opening and closing `<li>` for a menu item.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param string   $item_output The menu item's starting HTML output.
         * @param WP_Post  $menu_item   Menu item data object.
         * @param int      $depth       Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         * @param stdClass $args        An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         */
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $menu_item, $depth, $args );
    }

    /**
     * Ends the element output, if needed.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @since 5.9.0 Renamed `$item` to `$data_object` to match parent class for PHP 8 named parameter support.
     *
     * @see Walker::end_el()
     *
     * @param string   $output      Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param WP_Post  $data_object Menu item data object. Not used.
     * @param int      $depth       Depth of page. Not Used.
     * @param stdClass $args        An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function end_el( &$output, $data_object, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $output .= "</li>{$n}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you modify the code of the _original_ `Walker_Nav_Menu` class? That is something you should not to in the first place - your changes will be overwritten with the next WP update. You should create your _own_ class that _extends_ this one, and then use your own class when the menu output gets created.

Comment: `@param WP_Post  $data_object    Menu item data object.` - `WP_Post` does not have a `has_children` property.

Comment: But `$menu_item->classes` should contain the `menu-item-has-children` class, if the item has children, so perhaps check on that.